# Given two closed subsets $M$ and $N$ of $X$ show there exists open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $M \subset U$, $N \subset V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove one of the questions from *Metric Spaces: A Companion to Analysis* by Robert Magnus (Section 2.2, Question 25) and I am wondering if I am on the right track.

> 25. Let $M$ and $N$ be closed subsets of $X$. Show that there exists open subsets $U$ and $V$, such that $M \subset U$, $N \subset V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$

**My Attempted Proof:** Since $M$ and $N$ are both closed sets in $X$, then $M^c = X \setminus M$ and $N^c = X \setminus N$ are both open sets in $X$. Then for $x \in X \setminus M$ and $y \in X \setminus N$, there exists $\epsilon_x, \epsilon_y > 0$ such that $B(x, \epsilon_x) = \{x_0 \in X : d(x, x_0) < \epsilon_x\} \subset X \setminus M$ and $B(y, \epsilon_y) = \{y_0 \in X : d(y, y_0) < \epsilon_y\} \subset X \setminus N$. Then if $U = \bigcup_{x \in X \setminus M} B(x, \epsilon_x)$ and $V = \bigcup_{y \in X \setminus N} B(y, \epsilon_y)$, then $U \subset X \setminus M$ and $V \subset X \setminus N$, then $M \subset U \subset X$ and $N \subset V \subset X$.

I am not sure if this is on the right track, and how to proceed to show that the two sets $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Some assistance would be helpful.

Comment: You better require $M\cap N = \varnothing$

Comment: This is usually proved by considering the distance functions $d(S, x) = \inf_{y \in S} d(y, x)$ for $S = M, N$. See eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2872410/473276). I find it helpful to look at the example $X = \Bbb R^2$, $M = \{(x, y) \mid xy \ge 1\}$, $N = \{(x, y) \mid -xy \ge 1\}$ to understand why this construction is so delicate, and what goes wrong with the naive approach.

Comment: @KeqingQixing As pointed out by Didier, $M \cap N$ should be $\emptyset.$ This is because if $M \cap N \not = \emptyset,$ then $$M \subset U, N \subset V \implies 
 M \cap N \subset U \cap V \implies U \cap V \not = \emptyset.$$